# VBA excel macro to search open workbooks that have a specific text in the Filename

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, macros

I am a macro novice trying to add macro code that will find workbooks where first 6 characters in the file name are "Custom" and any characters after that are allowable. The code would be added to the macro below.  This is desired because I often have many other open workbooks with filenames that do not begin with characters "Custom" and  I do not want to collect any data from these.

I assume it will involve changing the line code which now reads

> "If wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then"

to something like:

> "If wb.Name  = custom*.xl?? Then"

- Excel 2010
- All the files are open.
- File extensions include .xls, .xlxm, .xlxs
- Include only files where first 6 letters of filename are 'custom...."

Code:

```
Sub getdata()

' Brings data (Tables)from workbooks that are open places the data in one large table in a workbook.

    Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, lr As Long..
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'Edit sheet name  
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks  
        If wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then  
            ''lr = wb.Sheets(1).Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row  ' goes to bottom of data  
            lr = wb.Sheets(1).Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious).Offset(-3, 0).Row              If Application.CountA(sh.Rows(4)) = 0 Then  
                wb.Sheets(1).Range("A4:P" & lr).Copy sh.Range("A4")  
            Else  
                wb.Sheets(1).Range("A4:P" & lr).Copy sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)  
            End If  
        End If  
    Next  
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there! We're not a script writing service, but can/will help with specifics.  What have you attempted so far?  Where exactly are you getting stuck coding what you want into the macro?

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is close, two remarks:

- always use `"` around strings
- VBA doesn't support wildcards for string comparison

use this:
`If Left(wb.Name,6) = "custom"`